# Implementing 3D Secure using CyberSource REST API

Tags: cybersource

I'm adding a support of CyberSource to our system and just got new requirement about 3D Secure support.

I've already implemented some flows using CyberSource REST API:

- [Payments](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-payments/GettingStarted.html)
- [Card tokenisation via Flexible token](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-flex/SAFlexibleToken.html)

I'm a little bit confused, because I can't find any information about implementation of Payer Authentication in conjunction with the REST integration. All I found is the documentation for [Simple Order API](https://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Payer_Authentication_SO_API/Payer_Authentication_SO_API.pdf) and [SCMP API](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Payer_Authentication_SCMP_API/Payer_Authentication_SCMP_API.pdf).

Am I missing something? Am I supposed to use any of the aforementioned docs or there is some separate document for REST API? Or I should use different integration method instead of REST?

Answer (score 0):

Update 6-14-18:  The payer authentication (3-D Secure) is now available with the REST API.

The payer authentication services are not available through the REST API at this time. I know they will be, but don't know when.

The only other option is using the SOAP API ([SOAP Toolkit](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/SOAP_Toolkits/SOAP_toolkits.pdf)) or pre-built client ([Simple Order API](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Getting_Started_SO/Getting_Started_SO_API.pdf)). SCMP is a legacy API and should not be used.